# Google chart legend pager issues on mobile

Tags: javascript, svg, charts

I'm working on a web-app which uses jQuery mobile and google chart to display loads of different types of analytics for a/many custom build platforms.

The above is not entirely relevant to my question, the issue I'm walking into is a high amount of legend values.

Ofcourse it'd be better to use less different values in our chart, but for some reason we do need 20ish items.

We're all fine with this and that it's clipped onto 2 or 3 pages within the legend.
My question though, does anyone know a simple solution to the browse buttons, we either want to change them or the touch field bigger, since it's really hard to click a small arrow with your big thumbs.

http://jsfiddle.net/3DP3F/1/

Example of trouble for thumbs icon.

Does anyone know of a decent way to keep our tabled and phone users happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot edit the size because it's an SVG `path`. The size of those can only be edited within the tag and not with css. The only option could be with JavaScript. You have to edit the attribute `d` and figure out higher dimensions as `path` only uses dimensions instead of `height` and `width`.

Play a bit around with

```
path{
 fill:red;
}
```

to see what you can do more with it.

This is the current tag from the left arrow:

```
<path d="M356,162L351,151L345,162Z" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#cccccc"></path>
```

Where `d` is the dimension.

Hope this helped you a bit though this is not the solution.

Comment: I'm aware of it's functionality, but there must be a way to trigger it otherwise perhaps, add an overlay in HTML to catch the click so mobile users have less issues.

Or maybe a decent way to alter the values.

Comment: I think the only way you could really alter its values is to change the `d` attribute with jQuery. It would look something like `$("path").attr("d", "M356,162L351,151L345,162Z");`. I did not test it so it's only a guess how it possibly can be edited.

Comment: That would work I'm pretty sure, but it'd also change the entire chart ;).

It would rather be something using the nr whatever child. I'll keep this up though maybe someone knows.

Comment: I think nobody knows more about this subject. If you could mark my post as answer others can check it out and'll know it's the right answer. Thanks in advance!